# How concordant pairs are calculated in the R function rcorr.cens

Tags: r, hmisc

I was using rcorr.cens function in the R package Hmisc. Noticed the definitions for the outputs "relevant pairs" & "concordant" are hard to understand. In this example 4 sample points are used: A(1,0), B(2,1), C(3,0), and D(4,1).

I would expect number of pairs to be 4*(4-1)/2=6, but function gives 8, the concordant pairs should be A-B, A-D, and C-D, so 3, but function gives 6. How does this R function come up with those outputs?

```
library(Hmisc)
x=seq(1,4,1)
s=rep(0,4)
s[c(2,4)]=1

rcorr.cens(x,s)

       C Index            Dxy           S.D.              n        missing     uncensored Relevant Pairs 
          0.75           0.50           0.50           4.00           0.00           4.00           8.00 
    Concordant      Uncertain 
          6.00           0.00
```